# When was the middle stump camera invented in cricket?

Tags: cricket, equipment, history, trivia, technology

When was the middle stump camera invented in cricket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stump cameras were first used in 1992 cricket world cup, a tournament of [several innovations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992_Cricket_World_Cup#Firsts) in modern cricket like colored player clothing, white cricket balls, black sight screens etc.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109032022/http://specials.cricbuzz.com/t20-league/2013/innovations-zone/skills/14/Stump-Camera-and-Microphone).

Answer (score 0):

The first stump camera was developed in 1988 and used in Hobart, Tasmania for TCN channel 9.
The first stump was a modified original wooden stump drilled out to accept an aluminium tube carrying a Panasonic lipstick camera.
I know this because I built it for Warren Berkeley tcn 9 outside broadcast manager.

Answer (score -1):

Despite being mentioned in other answers, it was not the 1992 World Cup where Stump Cam was used for the first time! It was the 1990'1991 Benson & Hedges World Series Cup!

Comment: Please provide a reference